# How does A/B montage works?

Tags: sound-design, post-production, film, workflow, film-sound-design

I heard about A/B montage in school, but it was only mentioned once. And I know it has something to do with two tracks, and using it for easier automation and whatever else, when the perspective in sound changes because of visual perspective changing of course etc. I would like to learn that type of workflow, but cant find it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

A/B is also called checkerboarding.  You can use it for when a scene changes or anytime you need to apply processing that is radically different than the section of audio that came right before it.  It can be used in other ways as well, such as if room tones aren't matching between shots and long fades are needed.  I'm sure you already lay out tracks like that sometimes without knowing the specific term for what your doing.

Comment: but how do you do it

Comment: The very simplified version would be that Actor/Angle/Scene A would be on track 1 and Actor Angle/Scene B would be on track 2 so that you could have your settings for track 1 and radically different (if needed) settings on track 2. It can let you use less tracks in your edit or mix because your usually just switching off between a couple tracks.  Your edit will end up looking like a checkerboard.  If you don't already have it, I'm pretty sure the John Purcell book gives a better explanation and probably has photos also.  Its a great book to have in any event if you plan on doing audio post.